# Apply HTML To An Anchor?.. IF statement?

Tags: html, if-statement

How does this website change the blue t-head to green, when visiting an anchor link for a post? Like hi-lighting it... I need to do this on phpBB2 when jumping to an anchor link post.

http://www.thetechgame.com/Forums/p=36812822.html#36812822

Comment: Add this css line `a:visited{background:green}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:visited`:

```
a{
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  color: #FFF;
}

a:visited{
  background: green;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/69pmrfun/)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have a <td> that I need to apply a class to, when visiting an anchor. I have <td class="ttop"> , and when visiting an anchor, I need it to change to green by changing to <td class="ttop ttop-green">

Comment: you would need javascript to do something like this since `:visited` is a property of `a` tags and there isnt a pure css solution for this.

Comment: Oh, could you help me with how I could do this.? It's basically that I need to change <td class="ttop"> to <td class="ttop ttop-green" when viewing an anchored post. How is it done at http://www.thetechgame.com/Forums/p=36812822.html#36812822 ? It isn't css on that site